# Singleton on method with Context parameter

Tags: java, android, database

I code CRUD methods and wonder if it's useful to define my DAO class as singleton. While they have as a parameter the context of the activity that requires them.

I do not try to do it because I learned about the net. And I notice that the singleton is used in the classes that manage a database outside the activities

Comment: Exactly what do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a singleton. It's a recognised anti-pattern, and makes testing difficult. I would much rather inject in a concrete implementation, and have your service reference a DAO interface (allowing you to inject different implementations in)

Answer (score 0):

Basically I have a database with each table linking to a DAO class and a class that defines my table. My DAO class when I instantiate it I have in parameter the context to activate it. This makes it possible not to have calls from everywhere. Do I still need to implement a singelton?